# Detect if user scrolls more than 20px no matter where it's on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Is it possible to detect if the user scrolls more than 20px wherever it's on the page??

I mean, in a one page design, I need to remove a class when the user scrolls more than 20px but not only from the top of the document.

Each time he opens a popup, a class is added to the popup in question, once the user scrolls, I would like to remove this class.

Repeat this function no matter where it's on the page.

My current code :

```js
$(window , 'body').on('scroll', function() {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    $("#wrapper").removeClass('newsletter-opened');
        $("#newsletter").removeClass('opened');
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: `$(window , 'body')` it is not correct?

Comment: Yes, it is. Actually that is exactly like `$('body').find(window)`. Remove `body` from the selector, then `if( $(this).scrollTop() > 20 ) { /*...*/ }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery for that.

With my solution, if user has scroll 200px when he come on your page if he scroll to top or bottom with minumum 20px of scroll your changes was called.

```
var userScroll = $(document).scrollTop();

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
   var newScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
   if(userScroll - newScroll > 20 || newScroll - userScroll > 20){
      $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
      $("#wrapper").removeClass('newsletter-opened');
      $("#newsletter").removeClass('opened');
   }
}
```

EDIT:

After look your jsFiddle, i know what you want, just check that :

Just define the scroll at the moment when popin is enable and make your job only when the popin has class `opened`

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("a.open-newsletter").on( "click", function() {
        $("#newsletter").toggleClass('opened');
        userScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
        return false;
    });

    $(window , 'body').on('scroll', function() {
        if ( $("#newsletter").hasClass('opened') ) {
            var newScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
            if (userScroll - newScroll > 100 || newScroll - userScroll > 100) {
                $("#newsletter").removeClass('opened');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Cyril! Thanks a lot for your fast answer. Actually, your solution works only from the top of the page. If I open my popup in the middle of the page and I scroll, the popup is hidden immediately without to wait the 20px :/

Comment: Can you make a fiddle to see exactly what you want please ?

Comment: @user3817291 you want disable popin only when the popin is enable and user scroll at least 20px ?

Comment: Once you clicked on Get notified, the popup appears. 
I want to close it once the user has scrolled more than 20px no matter in which sense.
Works when the popup is opened at top of the document but not after.

Comment: @user3817291 Click on the check button on left for make this response good for the topic

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the Scroll function will take effect on every pixel the page is scrolled, which is too heavy in terms of performance.

As a result, if you just take the difference between newScroll & userScroll, the result may be wrong sometimes (because the new and old scroll positions will be updated shortly as the page is moving along)

Therefore, we can just set a time interval which checks the scroll position every 250 milliseconds (this will both increase performance and give time for users to scroll more than 20px as your requirement):

```
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 20;

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Return if they scroll less than 20px (delta)
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // Do what you want here
    console.log("lastScrollTop: ",lastScrollTop, " - newScroll: ", st);
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    $("#wrapper").removeClass('newsletter-opened');
    $("#newsletter").removeClass('opened');     

    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

**EDITED VERSION BELOW:**

(according to your fiddle, I deleted "use strict" and commented out the $('.navbar-collapse') & $('#wrapper'))

Would you mind trying this again (seems that some previous errors just prevented my code from executing)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a.open-newsletter").on( "click", function() {
            $("#newsletter").toggleClass('opened');
            return false;
    });

    var didScroll;
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    var delta = 20;
    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        didScroll = true;
    });

    setInterval(function() {
        if (didScroll) {
            hasScrolled();
            didScroll = false;
        }
    }, 250);

    function hasScrolled() {
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();

        // Return if they scroll less than 20px (delta)
        if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
            return;

        // Do what you want here
        console.log("lastScrollTop: ",lastScrollTop, " - newScroll: ", st);
        //$('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
        //$("#wrapper").removeClass('newsletter-opened');
        $("#newsletter").removeClass('opened');     

        lastScrollTop = st;
    }

});
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your devotion, I just created a fiddle as your answer does not work for me : https://jsfiddle.net/d7futsh0/

Comment: Oh I see, so you've just made it work with the current code, right? If so, that's good!
My solution works on many other cases, however, it is complicated (the function should be outside of the $(document).ready function)

Comment: Hey! Actually, it works when you're at top of the document but if your scroll for example 500px and re-open the popup, when you will scroll the popup will disappear immediately without to what the "delay in px"

Comment: I've just added an edit, would you mind trying again? I tested with your fiddle, and after scrolling down, opening popup again, scrolling a bit, and the popup disappears